Firefox Browser blocking execution of asynchronous JavaScript?
I wrote simple Tests for my webapplication in the Selenium Framework, which works completly fine for Chrome and Edge.
But only in Firefox the asynchronous Script gets timeouted, could be an issue with the security settings of Firefox itself, i couldn't find any related settings in about:config.
Also i  have already installed the lastet geckodriver version.

Can you provide a minimal working example of the testing code that's causing the trouble in Firefox?

@CrazyRedd for example:  async function waitForTilesLoaded(driver) {
await driver.executeScript(() => {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'tilesloaded', function () {
resolve(true);
});
});
});
}   i get 30 000ms timeout error in the node terminal

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

From the code you provided in a reply to my comment, I believe your trouble is likely related to how you're returning a Promise from your executed script.
Your current code:
async function waitForTilesLoaded(driver) {
    await driver.executeScript(() => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'tilesloaded', function () {
                resolve(true);
            });
        });
    });
}

I suggest you try using executeAsyncScript instead of executeScript. Have a look at how you can use it here:
https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/javascript/WebDriver.html#executeAsyncScript
Try using the following instead:
async function waitForTilesLoaded(driver) {
    await driver.executeAsyncScript(function() {
        var callback = arguments[arguments.length - 1];
        google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'tilesloaded', () => callback());
    });
}

Note that you have to be careful how your function accesses this callback. Take a look at the examples they give for the executeAsyncScript function in their docs.
